# Subprogram transactional behavior in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a subprogram in PL/SQL that has

```
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION
```

directive.

It seems like only in this subprogram(there's a set of procedures that are used in the same way, but they don't have this pragma) changes in the transaction that called this procedure are not visible!

I don't get it.

Other procedures see changes made within transactions, except for those who have this pragma directive. Is it a toll for being able to do separate commits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, an autonomous transaction is exactly that - autonomous and separate from the transaction from which it is called; neither can see the other's changes until they are committed.  There are very few good reasons to use autonomous transactions: the main valid use that comes to mind is error logging.  Often they are misused, particularly in triggers to avoid the "table is mutating" exception.  What is the purpose of the autonomous transaction in your procedure?

Comment: +1 for "There are very few good reasons to use autonomous transactions". I wish all developers would consider whether they really need an AT at all.

Comment: Well, it is necessary to maintain some resources in consistent state, thus commiting changes in them in separate transaction to support parallel access to them. I wish I could say more but its the most detail level I'm allowed to go in :(. Thanks anyway, I will bang my head at few other solutions. If there's any..

Comment: The way to maintain consistent state and have parallel access is surely to **not** use an autonomous transaction?!

Comment: Was it a question or an outbreak of indignation? :)

Comment: @Anton - Are you sure that you aren't looking to use savepoints rather than autonomous transactions?  Using autonomous transactions do the exact opposite of maintaining resources in a consistent state.

Answer (score 5):

Code that has an `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` pragma that is not simply doing some logging that you don't want to be rolled back if the parent transaction fails is almost always a bug.

Autonomous transactions are truly autonomous.  They are completely independent of the parent transaction.  It is expected that code inside an autonomous transaction cannot see uncommitted changes made in any other transaction including the transaction that was underway in the current session before the autonomous transaction was started.

If you are coming from a SQL Server background, autonomous transactions are completely different animals than nested transactions.

Answer (score 4):

[Autonomous transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/autotransaction_pragma.htm#LNPLS01302) subprograms run in their own independent transaction. They act in exactly the same way as if you opened an extra connection and ran the procedural logic before returning to your main transaction.

Since they are independent, they don't see uncommitted changes from their parent transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, when you use PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTIONS it allows the stored procedure to be run as a "fire and forget" process.  This is also necessary if you are going to have commits inside certain procedures as it does not allow rollbacks.

Typically if you are referencing a stored procedure containing commits from a trigger, it will need to have this line at the beginning.  We have also run into needing this on our stored procedures being called from web services if they contain commits.